# Display customer phone in "New Order" Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-data, email-notifications

In WooCommerce, How can we show the Telephone number of a customer in "New Order" email notifications?

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far

Comment: Now in the order confirmation email only the billing address I can't show the phone number How can i do it ?

Comment: Do you now the variable that responsible for customer data like phone & Email?

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the template and add `<?php echo $order->get_billing_phone();?>` for phone and `<?php echo $order->get_billing_email();?>` for email

Example:

```
<tr>
   <td width="100%" height="36" class="em_spc_5">Phone: <?php echo $order->get_billing_phone();?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="100%" height="36" class="em_spc_5">Email: <?php echo $order->get_billing_email();?></td>
 </tr>
```